# Regex find character point number point number

Tags: c#, regex

How can i find with regular expression where [Capital Letter][Point][Number][Point][Number]

Examples : B.1.1.1 , B.1.2 , B.1.2.3.

Sometimes it can finish with point. 
Length or string is smaller than 9.

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: I have list of strings some them like (B.1.1.1) or (B.1.2.3.) I need to remove them.

Comment: Normal string looks like (B.1.2 SomeText)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
[A-Z]\.(\d\.?)+
```

it must start with a capital letter and a dot, and then will be followed by one more "number with optional following dot".

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this pattern will be at the beginning of each string, and not in between.

```
^[A-Z][.\d]*
```

Examples:

B.1.1.1 > Matches
B.1.2.3. > Matches
B.1.2 SomeText > Matches B.1.2